# A basis of Complement Space.

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear algebra, a complement to a subspace of a vector space is another subspace which forms an internal direct sum. Two such spaces are mutually complementary.

Formally, if $U$ is a subspace of $V$, then $W$ is a complement of $U$ if and only if $V$ is the direct sum of $U$ and $W$, $V=U\oplus W$, that is:

$V=U+W$

$U\cap W=\emptyset$

I am solving an exercise in which $V=\mathbb{R}^8$ and $U$ has the following basis

\begin{equation}
B_U=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{c}
  0 \\
  3 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
  1 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
  0
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  -1 \\
  0 \\
  2 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
  1 \\
  0 \\
  0
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  0 \\
  -2 \\
  0 \\
  1 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
  1 \\
  0
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  0 \\
  0 \\
  -3 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
  1
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  -1 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
  3 \\
  0 \\
  0
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  0 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
  -1 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
  -3 \\
  0
\end{array}\right)\right\}
\end{equation}
The exercise asks me to calculate a basis for complement $W$. Due to the definition of complement space, I have to find two elements of $\mathbb{R}^8$ which added to $B_U$ do not change the linear independence of the elements of $B_U$.

From the operational point of view, as I find these two elements?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your given vectors in a matrix, fill up with the standard unit vectors
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  3 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 2 & 0  &-3 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1  &0  & 0  & -1& 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0  & 3 & 0& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0  & 0  & -3& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1  & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now compute a row echelon form using row operations. 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1  &0  & 0  & -1& 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1  & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 2 & 0  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & -2& 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 &-3 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0  &0 & 0 & 0 &   3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 3\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 &-3 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So, if I didn't make a computation error, $e_1$ and $e_2$ will span a complement for your given $U$, as their columns correspond to pivot columns in the row echelon form.

Comment: Thanks. But: who are $e_1, e_2$?

Comment: @Mark: $e_i$ refers to the vector with a $1$ in the $i$th position and $0$s everywhere else.

Comment: This is not very clear as an answer. I suppose that "their columns" refers to the columns that _originally_ held $e_1$ and $e_2$, in other words columns $7$ and $8$. Also, I think there should be a few words on why the row echelon form says anything about the original problem to begin with, and more specifically why the pivot columns among the added columns identify a set of standard basis vectors that span a complementary subspace.