# How to find the basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

So if there is a n-dimensional space $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ over a field, How can I find a basis which together with $(c_1, c_2, ..., c_n)$ (where all $c_i$'s are non-zero constants from this field) forms a basis for the whole n-dimensional space? Thank you so much.

Comment: There isn't such a thing - "the complementary subspace"

Comment: What I mean is all the elements in the space that does not belong to the subspace generated by (c_1, c_2, ..., c_n). Sorry for the confusion, maybe I need to change it to complement subspace?

Comment: What you are referring to is just "the complement", and it is _not_ a subspace, hence it has no basis.

Comment: Could you please explain why it is not a subspace?

Comment: I think my problem is kinda like this question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238551/a-basis-of-complement-space

Comment: For one, a subspace always has $0$ as an element.  The complement of a subspace will not have $0$.

Comment: I have done some modification to the original problem.

Comment: As you have been told, the complement of a subspace does not have the zero element, so it isn't a subspace, so it doesn't have a basis. Now, maybe what you want is a set of $n-1$ vectors which, together with your one vector, form a basis for the original $n$-dimensional space. But you had better think real hard about exactly what question it is you want to ask, and ask it precisely, because it is not our job to read your mind.

Comment: Sorry, already modify the question.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the $c_i$ cannot be all equal to zero as a basis cannot contain the zero vector.

After that, you can use the incomplete basis theorem: a linear independent family can be completed to a basis by picking vectors from an existing basis.  So use the canonical basis $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$. You'll be able to pick by induction $n-1$ vectors from this canonical basis to complete your initial vector to a basis.

Comment: Is there any algorithm I can apply or maybe I can directly use the method mentioned in this link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238551/a-basis-of-complement-space?

Comment: Yes you can use the method of that post. You just need to learn what are row operations. My answer was more on a general standpoint: you can always complement a linear independent family of vectors to get a basis with vectors from an existing basis. There are then several ways to chose those vectors. Row operations is one. But not the only one.

Comment: This complement is not unique right? If I have this vector (c_1, c_2, ..., c_n), and suppose I consider all the other vectors which are linearly independent from this particular vector, it seems these vectors do not constitute a subspace. Is there any special name for this set?

Comment: For sure the complement is not unique. Take the example of a line in a plane. All lines that are different from the one given are complements. In French we say "sous-espace supplémentaire" for such complement. I don't know in English.

Comment: Is there any other way to represent this set other than directly calling it the whole plane minus this particular line? I mean the way similar to using a basis to represent a subspace? It would be very useful to me if I can represent this set using a finite set, and it also kinda surprise me that the whole plane can be represented by a finite basis, but we cannot represent a subset of the plane using a finite set?

Comment: Is it true that any element in this set can be represented as a linear combination of the basis for the orthogonal complement of the subspace generated by this vector and this vector itself? Intuitively it seems to be true right?

Comment: How, user195867, would you use a finite set to represent the set of all points in the $xy$-plane leaving out the $x$-axis? I think the best you could do would be to call it the set of all $a(1,0)+b(0,1)$ with $b\ne0$. In general, if $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is a basis, and you want to exclude the scalar multiples of $v_1$, you could say all $a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n$ with at least one of $a_2,\dots,a_n$ not zero. If you're working over the reals, you could insist on $a_2^2+\cdots+a_n^2\ne0$.

Comment: Are we OK now??

Comment: Sorry for late response. Yes, I think the problem is clear now.